# Do I need another Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen

I have a Schengen visa, multiple entry, issued by Dutch embassy, London; valid till October 2019 and i am travelling Amsterdam from 27-29 july. However, I am planning to attend a seminar in Ireland in September, which was not planned earlier and not mentioned in previous schengen visa application.
Now, Do I need another Schengen visa? If yes, will this be granted within existing visa validity?

Comment: The Republic of Ireland or Northern Ireland?

Comment: The name of the republic is actually Ireland. Assume it is the republic unless otherwise is stated.

Answer (score 18):

The Republic of Ireland is not part of the Schengen area - your Schengen visa is not valid there.

Depending on your citizenship you may need a new visa specifically for the Republic of Ireland.

Edit:

'Ireland' could, of course, mean Northern Ireland. Northern Ireland is part of the UK and is also not part of the Schengen area. You may still need a visa but you'd apply to the UK instead of Ireland.

Note also that visas from Ireland and the UK are generally not valid to travel across the border between the two countries. There are exceptions for some nationalities depending on which way you travel.

Thanks to [Traveller](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/60926/traveller) for picking that up in the comments.

Comment: Since the OP applied for their previous visa in London, it's likely that they're legally resident in the UK, in which case Northern Ireland shouldn't be a problem at all. (Also the "Note also" paragraph could sound like even if you have visas from _both_ countries you need some special additional permission to _cross the border_ between them).